# Can't remove dependency from build.gradle? (assert pluginDirectory.exists())

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have a build.gradle, and have previously added but then replaced a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    // I WANT THIS
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'new_project/android/src/main', include: ['*.jar'])
    // I dont want this
    //    implementation fileTree(dir: 'old_project/android/src/main', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

But Gradle (using 6.1.1) has cached the old one dependency and doesn't want to replace it with my new one (even after syncing and reimporting gradle project), even when it can't find the old dependency (I deleted old_project), so its giving me a

```
Cause: assert pluginDirectory.exists()
       |               |
       |               false
       old_project/android
```

I could not even find this `assert` code in any of the project code, so I don't know what to do.

I have also tried to remove the module from the project settings, but Android Studio re-added it when I pressed 'apply' or 'ok' of the Settings window.

---

I am trying to use a modified flutter repository, and old_project is actually `/usr/local/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.5.8+2`, and new project is a repo I created (cloning the project from github).

---

It turns out that Flutter is reading a file that it created initially:

```
def moduleProjectRoot = project(':flutter').projectDir.parentFile.parentFile
def pluginsFile = new File(moduleProjectRoot, '.flutter-plugins-dependencies')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'old_project/android/src/main', include: ['*.jar'])
```

You can remove local **`jar/module`** in this way

[image]

**FYI** - You can open  **`settings.gradle`** found under Gradle and remove specific module. If you want to remove **`':library'`** then

**OLD**

```
include ':app', ':library', ':viewpagerdotsindicator'
```

**Now**

```
include ':app', ':viewpagerdotsindicator'
```

Finally, **`Invalidate Caches/Restart`**

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I tried this, but it actually re-added it after hitting `apply` or `ok`

Comment: @BenButterworth well, Delete Gradle folder and clean-rebuild-restart

Comment: I deleted the `/gradle` folder in my project, but it contains only the `wrapper` folder. The error continues for me

Comment: @BenButterworth remove from `settings.gradle` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, However I only have `include ':app'` the whole time.

Comment: Your help is helpful, as I have looked at settings.gradle and found `apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"`. Now I am looking there

Comment: @BenButterworth Now move ahead

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to modify external Java/ Kotlin code from Flutter plugins, and was importing their code directly using `app/build.gradle`, using

```
 implementation fileTree(dir: '/usr/local/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.5.8+2/android/src/main', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Instead, you should fork the repository, and add the local path of the project to `pubspec.yaml`:

```
  # No longer using the remote version commented below
  # camera: ^0.5.8+2
  camera:
    path: '/path/to/repo/plugins/packages/camera'
```

---

**Old answer, before I realised `fileTree` did not do anything:** From your flutter project, `rm .flutter-plugins-dependencies`, **or**

from inside your Android Studio folder, `rm ../.flutter-plugins-dependencies`

**Why?** When adding these plugins, Flutter creates `.flutter-plugins-dependencies` in the Flutter project folder, not the `android` sub-folder. Because it is one level up (not in Android Studio), and ignored using `.gitignore`, it took me a very long time to find this.